# What would be a good CPU for IntelliJ for under $300

Tags: processor, pc, desktop, performance

What CPU is best optimized for running a program like Intellij?

I'm looking to build a computer best optimized for running Intellij. This computer will be a non-gaming computer so to remove some of the bloat that comes along with gaming rigs.

Anything that involves graphics I hope to keep to a minimum, I'm strictly looking for performance.

If IntelliJ project specifications are required to answer this question then I'll more than happy to provide the information required.

[Heres is a link to my original question for reference](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/15901/21143)

Answer (score 1):

Compiling programs is mostly multi core, so you could get a Ryzen 7 5700X, which also has good single core performance (which is useful when testing applications). If it does not fit in your budget (in Belgium I can get it for €310) you can also get a 5600X, which is just a bit slower in compiling big programs.

Comment: You have been my guru while I take my first baby steps into the world of hardware, thank you. Would it be better to use the AMD Ryzen 7 5700X over the Ryzen 7 3700X or is the 5700X more for single-core performance?

Comment: Also, the project is architected as a [microservice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) design so many programs will be deployed simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that 5700X was a thing, but here in Belgium, it is out of budget. (Oh wait 3700X is also, yes, 5700X is better, even than 5600X, bruh). Please check out my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend a AMD Ryzen™ 5 5500 simply due to the fact that it is a common and affordable CPU that will definitely support programs like Intellij and many of JetBrains CPU Consuming Software. It has 6 cores and a base clock of roughly 3.6 Giga hertz and a maximum boost clock of up to about 4.2 Giga Hertz. I hope this helps answer your question.