# Does a programming computer made for IntelliJ require a GPU?

Tags: graphics-cards, pc, desktop, performance

[My quest to build the most optimized IntelliJ computer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/15901/21143) continues. One part at a time.

*If you haven't seen my [other questions](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/15906/21143) then here's the run down:*

> I'm looking to build a computer best optimized for running Intellij. This computer will be a non-gaming computer so to remove some of the bloat that comes along with gaming rigs.

> Anything that involves graphics I hope to keep to a minimum, I'm strictly looking for performance.

Obviously, I can't build a programming computer for IntelliJ without a GPU (or can I?). IntelliJ has a GUI but a assume that the rendering for this could just be done by the CPU.

**So my question is do I even need a GPU for this type of project? If the answer is yes then what is the minimum level of GPU I can use for under $300?**

Answer (score 1):

A cheap GPU like a GT 1030 will be your minimum to run your OS (preferably Linux, since it's free). IntelliJ does not need much more than that. Depending of if your application requires OpenCL though, the Radeon RX 6500XT is better, if your app uses openCL. Both GPU's are availible under €300 where I live, but because of chip shortages, prices may vary (a lot)